# How to calculate mean and standard deviation of a set of images

Tags: python, image, numpy, machine-learning

I would like to know I to calculate the `mean` and the `std` of a given dataset of `RGB` images.
For example, with *imagenet* we have `imagenet_stats: ([0.485, 0.456, 0.406], [0.229, 0.224, 0.225]`.
I tried:

```
rgb_values = [np.mean(Image.open(img).getdata(), axis=0)/255 for img in imgs_path]
np.mean(rgb_values, axis=0)
np.std(rgb_values, axis=0)
```

I am not sure that the values I get are correct.
Which could be a better implementation?

Comment: @VladimirFokow Yes, I assume that `imagenet_stats` are calculated per pixel.

Comment: Related question: Explanation of [`imagenet_stats `](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58151507/14627505)

Comment: This explains how to calculate the `mean` and the `std` of a dataset of `RGB` images: [How imagenet mean and std derived?](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/77084/136526) (Data Science Stack Exchange).

Answer (score 4):

## Two solutions:

- The first solution iterates over the images. It is **MUCH slower** than the second solution, and it uses **the same amount of memory** because it first loads and then stores *all the images* in a list. So it is strictly worse than the second solution, unless you will change how your images are loaded - load and process them one by one from disc.
- The second solution needs to hold **all images** in memory at the same time. It is **MUCH faster**, because it is fully vectorized.

---

### First solution (iterating over the images):

For each channel: **R**, **G**, **B**, here is how to calculate the `mean`s and `std`s of all the pixels in all the images:

#### Requirement:

Each image has the same number of pixels.

If this is not the case - use the second solution (below).

```py
images_rgb = [np.array(Image.open(img).getdata()) / 255. for img in imgs_path]
# Each image_rgb is of shape (n, 3), 
# where n is the number of pixels in each image,
# and 3 are the channels: R, G, B.

means = []
for image_rgb in images_rgb:
    means.append(np.mean(image_rgb, axis=0))
mu_rgb = np.mean(means, axis=0)  # mu_rgb.shape == (3,)

variances = []
for image_rgb in images_rgb:
    var = np.mean((image_rgb - mu_rgb) ** 2, axis=0)
    variances.append(var)
std_rgb = np.sqrt(np.mean(variances, axis=0))  # std_rgb.shape == (3,)
```

#### Proof

... that the `mean` and `std` will be same if calculated like this, and if calculated using all pixels at once:

Let's say each image has `n` pixels (with values `vals_i`), and there are `m` images.

Then there are `(n*m)` pixels.

The `real_mean` of **all pixels** in all `vals_i`s is:

```
total_sum = sum(vals_1) + sum(vals_2) + ... + sum(vals_m)
real_mean = total_sum / (n*m)
```

Adding up the means of each image individually:

```
sum_of_means = sum(vals_1) / m + sum(vals_2) / m + ... + sum(vals_m) / m
             = (sum(vals_1) + sum(vals_2) + ... + sum(vals_m)) / m
```

Now, what is the relationship between the `real_mean` and `sum_of_means`? - As you can see,

```
real_mean = sum_of_means / n
```

---

Analogously, **using the formula for standard deviation**, the `real_std`  of **all pixels** in all `vals_i`s is:

```
sum_of_square_diffs =  sum(vals_1 - real_mean) ** 2
                     + sum(vals_2 - real_mean) ** 2
                     + ... 
                     + sum(vals_m - real_mean) ** 2
real_std = sqrt( total_sum / (n*m) )
```

If you look at this equation from another angle, you can see that `real_std` is basically the **average of average variances** of `n` values in `m` images.

---

#### Verification

**Real `mean` and `std`:**

```py
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
vals = rng.integers(1, 100, size=100)  # data

mu = np.mean(vals)
print(mu)
print(np.std(vals))
```

```
50.93                 # real mean
28.048976808432776    # real standard deviation
```

**Comparing it to the image-by-image approach:**

```py
n_images = 10
```

```py
means = []
for subset in np.split(vals, n_images):
    means.append(np.mean(subset))
new_mu = np.mean(means)

variances = []
for subset in np.split(vals, n_images):
    var = np.mean((subset - mu) ** 2)
    variances.append(var)

print(new_mu)
print(np.sqrt(np.mean(variances)))
```

```
50.92999999999999     # calculated mean
28.048976808432784    # calculated standard deviation
```

---

#### Second solution (fully vectorized):

Using all the pixels of all images at once.

```py
rgb_values = np.concatenate(
    [Image.open(img).getdata() for img in imgs_path], 
    axis=0
) / 255.

# rgb_values.shape == (n, 3), 
# where n is the total number of pixels in all images, 
# and 3 are the 3 channels: R, G, B.

# Each value is in the interval [0; 1]

mu_rgb = np.mean(rgb_values, axis=0)  # mu_rgb.shape == (3,)
std_rgb = np.std(rgb_values, axis=0)  # std_rgb.shape == (3,)
```

Comment: Is it necessary to concatenate all the images? Maybe is more efficient to calculate the mean and std per image, the result should be the same

Comment: @Simone If ALL your images have the **exact same** number of pixels, then `overall_mean = sum(individual_means) / n_images`

Comment: In case all images have the same number of pixels, it is necessary only `sum(individual_means)`, right? Why `rgb_stds = np.std(rgb_values - rgb_means, axis=0)` it should be `rgb_stds = np.std(rgb_values , axis=0)`, right?

Comment: @Simone, about the mean of means: https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/133138

Comment: @Simone because in one of the links that I’ve posted I have read that when normalizing data, first you subtract the mean, and then you divide by `std` that is calculated on the result (after mean subtraction). But feel free to reverse the order. As I said, I don’t really know how they did it for `imagenet_stats`

Comment: About the sum of means: consider two examples: `((1+2)/2 + (3+4)/2 ) /2`, and `sum(1,2,3,4)/4`

Comment: If all the images have the same dimensions, is not necessary to divide by `N`. Regarding the `std`, maybe your formula is about `Standard Error of the Mean`

Comment: @Simone Well, if you don’t divide by n, you will get: `(1+2)/2 + (3+4)/2 = 5` while the real mean is `(1+2+3+4)/4=2.5` …

Comment: @Simone, added example as you wanted (processing images one by one) and proved the equations that I use. Also, with how you load your images, the second (my original) implementation is better - use *it*.

Comment: I think that in the second example the `std_rgb` will be exactly the same if you subtract `mu_rgb` from `rgb_values` or not. So I removed it