# Arbitary choosen values as std/mean for normalizatio. why?

Tags: pytorch, normalization

I have a question regarding the `z-score normalization` method.
This method uses the `z-score` to `normalize` the values of the dataset and needs a `mean/std`.
I know that you are normally supposed to use the `mean/std` of the dataset.
But I have seen multiple tutorials on *pytorch.org* and the *net* who just use the `0.5` for `mean/std` which seems completely arbitrary to me.
And I was wondering why they didn't use the `mean/std` of the dataset?

Example Tutorials where they just use 0.5 as `mean/std`: 
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/dcgan_faces_tutorial.html
https://medium.com/ai-society/gans-from-scratch-1-a-deep-introduction-with-code-in-pytorch-and-tensorflow-cb03cdcdba0f
https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/blitz/cifar10_tutorial.html#sphx-glr-beginner-blitz-cifar10-tutorial-py

Comment: Perhaps linking the tutorial as well would help.

Comment: Because sometimes they are not that relevant, then one provide the mean of the range `[0, 1.]`. I would say that it depends on the bias of the dataset.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do they know mean and std, the input value of transforms.Normalize](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57532661/how-do-they-know-mean-and-std-the-input-value-of-transforms-normalize)

Comment: I mean I know where they got the mean and std in the case you linked. They calculated the mean and std of the dataset. What I was wondering about are cases of people who just use 0.5 as mean/std for normalization without calculating the mean/std of the dataset which looks completely arbitrary to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you use the std/mean of your dataset to normalize the same dataset you are going to have after the normalization a **mean of 0** and an **std of 1**.
Where the **min/max** values of the normalized dataset are **not** in a **certain range**.

If you use **mean/std of 0.5** as a parameter for normalization of your dataset you are going to have a dataset in the **range** of **-1 to 1**.
And the **mean** of the normalized dataset will be **close to zero** and the **std** of the normalized dataset will be **close to 0.5**.

So to answer my question you use **0.5 as mean/std** when you want that your dataset is in a **range of -1 to 1**.
Which would be beneficial when using, for example, a tanh activation function in a neural network.